# Regex for "spaces", "dashes (-)", "apostrophes (')", and "letters"

Tags: objective-c, regex

I would like to use a regex for "spaces", "dashes (-)", "apostrophes (')", and "letters" in my objective-c app.

I have the following, but it does not allow spaces.

`NSString *fullNameRegex = @"^[a-zA-Z'\\-]$";`

Could someone help me add the spaces please? Thank you!

Comment: `^[ a-zA-Z'\\-]$` a space in the beginning will be just fine.

Comment: `NSString *fullNameRegex = @"^[\\sa-zA-Z'-]*$";` - add a whitespace `\\s` char class, and do not forget to let your string have 0 or more `*` or 1 or more (`+`) quantifier.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
NSString *fullNameRegex = @"^[\\sa-zA-Z'-]*$";
                              ^^^         ^
```

Add a whitespace \s char class, and do not forget to let your string have 0 or more (with `*`) or 1 or more (with `+` quantifier).